# Manifest merge failed when accessing old application

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When updating the old Mobile Application got this error.

I have tried editing the minimunSDK on my graddle but it doesn't change anything.

```
    Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.39.0] C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1fd161e35a069ed7796af08ad312a191\account-kit-sdk-4.39.0\AndroidManifest.xml 
            as the library might be using APIs not available in 14

Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 15,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook.accountkit" to 
        force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Comment: ok. Do you also have a question about this? It seems that the error is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.39.0 uses API level 15 in your application i suggest you to make minSdk level to 19.

Comment: Not only Sdk You need to update your support library also. Please share your build.gradle.

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.motasemx.itsproject"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

Answer (score 0):

The library which you are using has set it's min SDK to 15 but your app SDK is 14. Go to gradle file and update your SDK to 15. You can even upgrade your SDK to 16 as only rarest of the rare people are using devices below API 16.

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle(module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14                 <------------------------ Change this greater than 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```